# How to handle images of different sizes in flutter?

Tags: flutter, aspect-ratio, flutter-image

There are different images with different sizes and how can I handle those different sizes by rendering those image with the same height and width.

I have tried this code

```
return Row(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 80,
          width: 80,
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage(carImage),
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        )
      ],
    );
```

since images are of different sizes they are like one is small and another is big. The dimensions of the images are

Three images are used here

```
788x580
1032x568
789x705
```

But I need all the images to be the same size i.e., height and width. The images that I use are `PNG` its more likely to be an icon

Comment: Add a two screenshots, one with the current output and the another with expected output.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you want to cover the container box. Go for following ;
Note: BoxFit.cover is better fit to your case I guess

```
Image(
            image: AssetImage(carImage),
            fit: BoxFit.fill, // contain
```

to cover;

```
Image(
            image: AssetImage(carImage),
            fit: BoxFit.cover, // contain
```

Comment: I have also tried it but there is no change in it!

Comment: try container not sized box